# How to select all columns of a table - recursive

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I made a recursive function to select all columns of specific table in DB. 
But, some of my columns, have a comment with a name of other table, like this:

**table_invoice**
column: *id*
column: *client_id*, comment: **table_client**
column: *type_id*, comment: **table_type**
column: *description*

So, if a column has a comment, I need to get into the table and select all its columns as well, and so on.

Now i need help to stop the function and return the array with all columns.
When i do `echo` into while, i can see all columns, but when i return, i just see the columns of the first table.

```
$columns = getAllColumns('table_invoice', $arr);

function getAllColumns($table, $arr)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$table'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $arr[] = array('column_name' => $row['COLUMN_NAME'], 'table_name' => $table);
        //echo $row['COLUMN_NAME'];  //this works fine, show all columns
        $comment = $row['COLUMN_COMMENT'];
        if(!empty($comment))
        {
            getAllColumns($comment, $arr);
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Can someone help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: And you are not using SQL JOINS because?

Comment: I can't use JOIN because i dont know how many tables i have to read.

Comment: I just have the first table, the others I dont know, I can have just one, but I can have 2 or 3 tables too.

Comment: And why that is a problem? Left join is still part of joins.

And you can always build dynamic joing query based on previous select and checking for comments (but i dont know why someone would be doing it this way.)

Comment: The comments seem to define foreign key relationships. Do you have the actual foreign keys defined? If yes, then you can use this information to actually join views in information_schema and get all fields from the related tables as well.